# group by doesn't give results with where clause

Tags: sql, oracle

As soon as I add a where clause to my query, I don't get any results any more despite rows matching the conditions.

(yes begindatum is a date)

```
SELECT COUNT(cursus) AS inschrijvingen,
       cursus,
       begindatum
FROM   inschrijvingen
WHERE  begindatum BETWEEN TO_DATE('01-JAN-99', 'DD-MON-YY') 
                      and TO_DATE('31-DEC-99', 'DD-MON-YY')
GROUP BY cursus,
         begindatum;
```

All the rows that have a begindatum in 1999, instead I don't get any results

Comment: Why are you using two-digit years? Why make Oracle guess (and potentially get it wrong)? Try using four-digit years instead, and seeing if that gets you the rows you think you should get.

Comment: I'm using two digit years because that is the format used in the data.however using 4 digit years did solve the problem for some reason kinda confused but thanks!

Comment: If the column holding the data is of DATE datatype, then no, it is not using two-digit years; it is using four-digit years but your display is only showing two of them. It is extremely good practice to always state the full year especially when you're specifying a specific date to filter on. You might want to look up the difference between the `YY` and `RR` format masks, which may help you understand why using `YY` on a year of 99 will return dates with a year of `2099` rather than the `1999` I suspect you're after.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is that `TO_DATE('01-JAN-99', 'DD-MON-YY')` translates to `01-JAN-2099`.

There are 2 possible solutions:

1) Use 4 digit years: `TO_DATE('01-JAN-1999', 'DD-MON-YYYY')`

2) Use RR instead of YY: `TO_DATE('01-JAN-99', 'DD-MON-RR')` translates to `01-JAN-1999`.

Answer (score 0):

Use the `DATE` keyword to put in dates using ISO standard formats:

```
SELECT COUNT(cursus) AS inschrijvingen, cursus,
       begindatum
FROM inschrijvingen
WHERE begindatum BETWEEN DATE '1999-01-01' AND DATE '1999-12-31'
GROUP BY cursus, begindatum;
```

You should never use two-digit years.  You could use `TO_DATE()`, but that is just clunky when you can explicitly add date literals as dates.

Further, the Oracle `DATE` data type includes times.  That means that the above may not include the last day of the year.  Instead of `BETWEEN`, I strongly recommend inequalities:

```
WHERE begindatum >= DATE '1999-01-01' AND
      begindatum < DATE '2000-01-01'
```